# Django Rest Framework not returning all fields after creation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Summary: I am using Django Rest framework to create a simple object (shown below). In the serializer, I am taking only required fields. However, I am not getting all fields back in POST response (like id, creation_date etc.). I am only getting the non-read-only fields back. Please help:

### Model

```
class Document(models.Model):
    owner = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    expiry_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    size = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    type = models.IntegerField(max_length=128, blank=True)
```

### Serializer

```
class DocumentCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('expiry_time', 'description', 'size', 'type', 'status')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'owner', 'created_time', 'update_time')
```

### View

```
class DocumentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
...
...

def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        serializer_class = DocumentCreateSerializer
    elif self.request.method == 'GET':
        serializer_class = DocumentGetSerializer
    elif self.request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer_class = DocumentUpdateSerializer
    elif self.request.method == 'PATCH':
        serializer_class = DocumentUpdateSerializer
    return serializer_class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want those fields to be returned then you should include them in `fields`:

```
class DocumentCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'created_time', 'update_time', 'expiry_time',
                  'description', 'size', 'type', 'status')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'owner', 'created_time', 'update_time')
```